# XSLT to concat attributes from multiple nodes into a single value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am wanting to create an XSLT 1.0 template that accepts a `node` parameter. The template would concat the attributes `@lot`, `@plan_type` and `@plan` from each node, join each node result by comma and output a string. See example XML below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RealEstate unique_id="045dcd20-0a69-4f2a-9bfa-c6b3e9b03281">
    <Title id="23bccbb0-2699-44bf-a672-9d2a27344254"
        instruction_id="10752681" is_primary="Yes" lot="184" plan="1212069"
        plan_type="DepositedPlan" tenure_type="Freehold" type="Torrens" />
    <Title id="045dcd20-0a69-4f2a-9bfa-c6b3e9b03281"
        instruction_id="10752681" is_primary="No" lot="185" plan="1212073"
        plan_type="DepositedPlan" tenure_type="Freehold" type="Torrens" />
    <Title id="c6b3e9b0-4f2a-44bf-a672-23bccbb04254"
        instruction_id="10752681" is_primary="No" lot="186" plan="1213002"
        plan_type="DepositedPlan" tenure_type="Freehold" type="Torrens" />
</RealEstate>
```

The `Title` node would be passed to the `node` parameter. Each `Title` node would then be looped to build and output the string `Lot 184 DepositedPlan 1212069, Lot 185 DepositedPlan 1212073, Lot 186 DepositedPlan 1213002`

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Elements nodes like `Title` are literally selected with a path `Title`, an attribute named `lot` is selected with `@lot`, as you already showed, the function to concatenate values is named `concat`, so where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't see what role a parameter would play here. Do you expect to have elements other than Title with the same attributes?

Comment: Thanks Martin and Michael. The role of the parameter is so the template can be used inline as part of a much bigger template and the input and output 'mapped' in an Altova MapForce design.

Comment: It would also be more generic so if a `<LandParcel />` node with `@lot`, `@plan` and `@plan_type` attributes were passed to the template the output would be the same.

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use?

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen unfortunately as stated I am limited to XSLT 1.0 (using libxslt)

Comment: I am afraid I still don't understand the requirement. There is no such thing as an "inline template" . Templates cannot be nested. I took a guess and posted an answer, but I don't see a practical use of this.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k your answer is on the right track and almost works. Please take a look at this documentation to understand the requirement for using custom XSLT functions in Altova MapForce. Link https://www.altova.com/manual/Mapforce/mapforcebasic/mff_xslt_func_example1.html

Comment: You can see my answer working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUM. It does not use any custom functions. I am afraid I know nothing about Altova MapForce and I do not intend to spend time changing that.

Comment: Appreciate your time @michael.hor257k and your solution works great (in a pure XSLT context). But unfortunately it needs to work as a function through `xsl:call-template` where the name of the node passed in `xsl:with-param` is used to match all elements by that name and reduce to a single value. I've expanded on your answer here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUM/1

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 and later I would use

```
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Title"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Title">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@lot, @plan_type, @plan" separator=" "/>
  </xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 1 that last template would be

```
  <xsl:template match="Title">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@lot, ' ', @plan_type, ' ', @plan)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic template that would extract the attributes from elements passed to it as a parameter, try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/RealEstate">
    <xsl:call-template name="get-attributes">
        <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="Title"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="get-attributes">
    <xsl:param name="elements" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:variable name="elem" select="$elements[1]" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$elem/@lot"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$elem/@plan_type"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$elem/@plan"/>
    <!-- continue -->
    <xsl:if test="count($elements) > 1">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="get-attributes">
            <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="$elements[position() > 1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
184 DepositedPlan 1212069, 185 DepositedPlan 1212073, 186 DepositedPlan 1213002
```

---

Note that the parameter passed to the named template is a **node-set**, not a **string**.

Comment: Elegant solution and with a bit of fiddling should be able to make it meet my needs. I would be happy to hire your expertise as I require further XSLT templates as functions as part of the project I am working on. Please make contact https://www.evosys.com.au/contact/

Comment: I sent you my email.